# Inner Join of three tables with dirty data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, T1, T2, T3

- T1 has columns A, B, C
- T2 has columns C, D, E
- T3 has columns E, F, G

The idea is to inner join all of them to get table T with columns A, B, C, D, E, F, G

I already now how to do the join of three tables, the problem is that the column E that is supposed to link T2 and T3 is very noisy, it supposed to be a numerical value, but it has all sort of values (text, punctuation, etc)

How would I use an if statement to do the inner join?

Here are examples of column E:

- In Table T2: 10000001, $4542, ., 1892348, 2347239 (noise are $4542 and '.')
- In Table T3: 10000001, 1892348, 2347239 (table 3 is rather clean)

The idea would be to match only the values that are numbers, but the standard JOIN breaks, since it cannot convert the $4542 to an int

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you provide examples of column E so that we can better assist? You can use value replacement or a conditional case as a join condition although performance will suffer for it but without knowing the extent of the data discrepancies it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Is the set of non-numeric characters predictable and set in stone? In other words, is it a set of characters like "$", ".", and maybe "_"?  If so, you can easily strip out those known characters to do your join. However, if it's unpredictable, or a very LARGE set, that would be unwieldy. Either way, you're going to have poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

User try_cast while making join to eliminate non numeric values. I did a fiddle with bad data on t2, but you can extend it for other tables as well.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f4b7/4

```
Select * from t2 inner join t3
ON t2.E=T3.E and
TRY_CAST(t2.E As INT) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify one thing. that do you want to exclude the noisy records or you need to join it after removing the special characters.

This can be done by case and patindex I believe.